# Error "Could not load Boto's S3 bindings."

Tags: django, boto, django-storage

I have followed the very terse guide provided for [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html), transitioned from local file storage, and have come up against this exception:

> Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.

settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxxxxx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxxxxxxx"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "images"
```

models.py

```
class CameraImage(models.Model):
...
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')#get_image_path)
```

What does that exception mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: duplicate here too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374247/django-storages-could-not-load-amazons-s3-bindings-errors/44728875#44728875

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From [looking at the source code](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/src/83fa2f0ba20c/storages/backends/s3boto.py#cl-24), it appears you need to have the [python-boto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto) library installed. This is also mentioned in the documentation you link to.

Comment: If you use `storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage` instead of `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage`, you will need both `boto` and `boto3` to be installed.

Answer (score 14):

There's been an update it's now "pip install boto"

Comment: Nowadays it's "boto3"