# Django Storages - Could Not Load Amazon's S3 Bindings Errors

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

Hey so trying to connect my user uploaded images to my S3 bucket so the images will store there. Using django storages (did some research, seemed to be what everyone suggested, but open to ideas)

Here's what I did:

Installed django storages

```
pip install django-storages
```

Added it to my INSTALLED_APPS

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'storages',
)
```

And added this code as well to settings.py

```
#settings.py
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '#################'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '#######################'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucketname'
```

Then I open the shell and run this to check

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
print default_storage.connection
...
ImproperlyConfigured: Could not load amazon's S3 bindings.
See http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=134
```

The link leads to a 404 error. Have been following along with the [documentation](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) and tried all 3 ways to set up DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE, and none of them work. See below.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'libs.storages.backends.S3Storage.S3Storage'
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing storage module libs.storages.backends.S3Storage

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
ImproperlyConfigured: Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.
```

How can I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do you have python-boto installed?
`pip install boto`
or
`pip install boto3`

Comment: forgot to install Boto. Now that Boto is installed, I open the shell to check (same process as above) and it comes back <class 'django.core.files.storage.DefaultStorage'> instead of S3Boto. What can I do here?

Comment: I have installed boto, and it did not work for me using 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'

Comment: @NicolasBouliane try using storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage

Comment: The problem isn't boto, django-storages is lacking proper python3 support, and is also using deprecated internal util functions in django.

Comment: @RyanCrowley really??

Comment: I had boto3 & botocore installed and ran into the same issue. django-storages requires boto 2.

Comment: It is more likely to be `pip install boto3` now

Answer (score 5):

Consider using boto3 instead of the older boto:

**requirements.txt:**

```
pip install django-storages
pip install boto3
```

**settings.py:**

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Answer (score 4):

Had this issue recently on **TravisCI** with a **Django** repo

Running `python manage.py compress` failed with the error:

> Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.

It happened to be an issue with boto trying to import `google-compute-engine` module that was not installed.

One way to fix the problem is by installing GCE engine with

`pip install google-compute-engine`

**EDIT:**

After investigation, it appears that this particular problem is due to Travis being on GCE, and GCE having a default `/etc/boto.cfg` file, which prompts boto to look for the GCE engine.

Another way to fix this problem on Travis without installing more dependencies is to set the default config with `BOTO_CONFIG` to point to nowhere by setting the variable

`BOTO_CONFIG=/tmp`

in your `travis.yml`

See this Issue
https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3741

Comment: This one fixed the problem for me when installing the edX Platform on a Google Cloud Engine VM. I have no idea why it did though :D

Comment: the other way os to define the default path to boto config to point to a non existant file. i can't remember why but there was a thread on the boto github, which i'd need to lookup to lknk here

Answer (score 1):

in answer to your comment above, it sounds like you are using the wrong settings, check this one:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the **First setting** you are trying i.e :

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'libs.storages.backends.S3Storage.S3Storage'
```

It means if the **code for storage is present in your 'libs.storages'** directory in your python path, then it should be accessed like above.

**But** if you have **installed django-storages using setup.py or pip or easy_install**, then following **2 options** are there:

A. **Amazone S3Python based library**:

> ```
> DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
> ```

- A simple interface between python and S3

B. **Python Boto based library**:

> ```
> DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
> ```

- Based on **python boto**, and supports much advanced  features e.g. connection pooling etc.
- But you are required to **install python boto** for using it, e.g `pip install boto`

Answer (score 0):

The link in the error message, http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=134, seems to work now (June 2014). If you follow it and download, unpack the .zip file and put `S3.py` on your Python path (i.e. in `site-packages`), it all works.