# Could not load Boto's S3 bindings. (Installed Boto)

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I'm trying to use s3 to store the users' upload files, I use django storages

> pip install django-storages

Added it to my INSTALLED_APPS

> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>
> ...
>
> 'storages',
>
> )

set variables in settings.py

> DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
>
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '#################'
>
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '#######################'
>
> AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucketname'

I have installed boto

> sudo pip install boto
>
> dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.9.0_dev-py2.7.egg
>
> Cleaning up...

When I save the item, the debug page of django jumps out,

> Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.
>
> See https://github.com/boto/boto

Any ideas? (I use mac os x 10.8.3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "Could not load Boto's S3 bindings."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574834/error-could-not-load-botos-s3-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

create a bash script: install_latest_boto.sh:

```
#install latest boto from source
cd /home/ubuntu/
sudo mkdir boto_temp
cd boto_temp
sudo git clone git://github.com/boto/boto.git
cd boto
sudo python setup.py install
```

---

on Django's settings - the django default storage will be s3:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
```

---

on your models.py:

```
class MyBaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @staticmethod
    def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
        if hasattr(instance, 'get_upload_folder'):
            return os.path.join(instance.get_upload_folder(), filename)
        else:
            raise Exception('Upload Folder is missing')

class User(MyBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=MyBaseModel.get_upload_path, default=None, blank=True, max_length=200)

    def get_upload_folder(self):
        upload_folder = 'users/images/orig'
        return upload_folder
```